How have mathematicians expressed preferences for the physical aesthetics of mathematics?
How have mathematicians expressed preferences for certain physical aesthetics of mathematics historically?
I’m curious about how certain things like a preference for handwriting mathematics, or using chalkboards have been expressed by mathematicians, and how such things may have influenced their work or teaching.

Once upon a time i came across a blackboard drawings book by George K Francis: A topological picture book. This mathoverflow question gives other answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440682/a-book-about-mathematical-drawing-on-the-blackboard . The Notices of the AMS often feature articles on maths and physical arts, sometimes quite involved. That may be about conformal mappings, physical realizations of hypercubes, surface singularities. Here are some of their articles: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fnotices+arts&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

I often think that the hardships of producing mathematical texts in the pre-LaTex era (say until the early or mid 1980ies) went hand in hand with a high kevel of abstraction and terseness. Entire books were written with typewriters and it was "expensive" to give all details an lots of concrete examples. For example, see Dellacherie & Meyer Probabilites et Potentiel.

Why do Stanford math professors still use chalk?

I guess you are willing to talk about mathematicians from before 1500, who wrote equations in words and diagrams (not symbolic algebra). For example, here is a proposition from Euclid:
https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-5bd4ec2acda9bba4f614eadbb7a38eb0
Chalkboards are convenient for sharing an idea with several people at once, perhaps to people who are far away from you. Writing in a notebook is useful for exploring ideas more deeply, over several days, and sharing thoughts with one person at a time. Ideas in a notebook will outlive you. Ideas on a chalkboard may also outlive you, depending on the audience.
For long-term work, a notebook is better. You can easily take this with you when you travel. People don't expect contents of a notebook to be erased.
